# Pie chart Slice color Change Dynamically in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to change Pie slice color dynamically. 
I want to change the color of the each slice which is there in the hidden variable assignedvalueZoom. Can some one help?

Comment: here is a live example http://jsfiddle.net/cindrella_agi/a6hW6/2/

Comment: You need to read the values from this field via JS and write them into the colors array for pie chart plot options. See: http://jsfiddle.net/a6hW6/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the color for each point in your data array like this:

```
for(j=0;j<name.length;j++) { 
    var temp = {
        x:name[j],
        y:value[j],
        color:color[j]
    };
    dataArrayFinal[j] = temp; 
}
```

This expicitly sets the x, y and color attributes of each data point.

http://jsfiddle.net/xktj3/